# Rails: ActiveRecord where vs merge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, active-relation

First, I am getting the review statuses between particular dates.

```
date_range = Date.parse(@from_date).beginning_of_day..Date.parse(@to_date).end_of_day

@review_statuses = ReviewStatus.where(updated_at: date_range)
```

Next, I need to apply an 'AND' condition.

```
    @review_cycle = params[:review_cycle]

    if @review_cycle.present?
      @review_statuses = @review_statuses.merge(
                           ReviewStatus.where(evidence_cycle: @review_cycle)
                                       .or(ReviewStatus.where(roc_cycle: @review_cycle)))
    end
```

Now for the below should I apply a 'where' or 'merge'.

```
@status = params[:status]

@review_statuses.where(evidence_status: :pass, roc_status: :pass) if @status == 'pass'
```

Can someone explain, when should we use `merge` instead of `where`?

Answer (score 10):

You generally want to use `where` except in special circumstances -- most commonly, to apply conditions to a secondary (joined) table in the query. This is becase

1. it's shorter / clearer / more idiomatic, and
2. `merge` has tricky edge cases: it *mostly* combines the two queries, but there are situations where one side's value will just override the other.

Given that, even your existing condition doesn't need `merge`:

```
# Unchanged
date_range = Date.parse(@from_date).beginning_of_day..Date.parse(@to_date).end_of_day
@review_statuses = ReviewStatus.where(updated_at: date_range)

# direct #where+#or over #merge
@review_cycle = params[:review_cycle]
if @review_cycle.present?
  @review_statuses = @review_statuses.where(evidence_cycle: @review_cycle).or(
                       @review_statuses.where(roc_cycle: @review_cycle))
end

# more #where
@status = params[:status]
@review_statuses = @review_statuses.where(evidence_status: :pass, roc_status: :pass) if @status == 'pass'
```

Comment: If `.or()` isn't working correctly that would be a matter for the Rails issue tracker, but I'm [quite confident](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052) the above is accurate and will do what you want.